# formula to get cell address relative to position within a range

Tags: excel-formula

[image]I have the following array formula:

```
 = MATCH(B2,DATE(YEAR(A1:AZ1),MONTH(A1:AZ1),1),0)
```

It returns 7, which is correct, refers the first relative position within the range A1:AZ1
However, I would like to get the relative cell address, i.e. A7

What I need to do is actually this:

```
     A       B            C 
 1-Jan-15   1-Feb-15    1-Mar-15

    AA        AB            AC
 1-Feb-15   1-Mar-15    1-Apr-15
```

I need to match the values in these ranges and get something like:

```
    AA        AB            AC
 1-Feb-15   1-Mar-15    1-Apr-15
   "B"         "C"         N/A
```

Comment: The question I always ask when someone wants a cell address;  Why?  What are you going to do with it?  is the address the final output or are you going to use it as a reference to get a value?

Comment: yes, I am using it to get a value

Comment: Then tie it with INDEX: `INDEX(A:A,MATCH(B2,DATE(YEAR(A1:AZ1),MONTH(A1:AZ1),1),0))` it will return the value in A7 as per your narrative.

Comment: Thank you Scott for your suggestion, but It has to be the address of the cell within the range i.e. "A7", not the value of the cell A7. I cannot use A:A as the range can extend from A1 to ZZ1

Comment: Maybe mock up some data, because there is a better way then returning a cell address that then is manipulated to get what you want.

Comment: i just added more explanations, thank you for looking into this.

Comment: Still not understanding.  You want the column but you get the column number with your current formula, so if you want a cell in that column how do you know which row to return?  Can you show a picture of your data?

Comment: I added a picture defining the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this will work.  You will need to change the references to your actual data.  Pay attention to what is relative and what is absolute in the formula.

In the picture this would be put in J12:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$T$4,ROW(1:1),MATCH(J$11,$D$1:$T$1,0))
```

Then it would be copied across and down.  The relative references will change to what is needed.